# formvalidation radio button validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using formvalidion.io in my form, and need to validate radio buttons.
The radio buttons have value **Yes** and **No**.
If **No** is picked, there should be a validation error, if **Yes**, then it should go through without any errors. How can I make this happen? Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/7owqedet/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container rootwizard" id="rootwizard">
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-radio">
    <input value="Yes" name="readDoc1" type="radio" id="Yes111"  />Yes
    </label> 

    <label class="btn btn-default btn-radio" for="No111">
    <input value="No" name="readDoc1" type="radio" id="No111" />No
    </label>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.rootwizard')
    // String Validation
    .formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        excluded: ':disabled',
        live: 'enabled',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },

        // Name Validation
        locale: validation_lang,
        fields: {
            readDoc1: {
                validators: {
                    notEmptyDoc: { }
                }
            }

    });
```

Comment: First off, you got a syntax error. At the end it is not }) but } });

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('input[type=radio][name=readDoc1]').change(function() {
         if (this.value == 'No') {
            alert('No')
         }
   });
```

And please rectify your syntax error

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7owqedet/3/)

Comment: I'm looking for a validation error, rather than an alert. so the form cannot be submitted